# MySQL Insert join table statement and update field on joined table

Tags: mysql

I have two table with column like this:

**Table aggthndet (Reference table)**

```
SELECT `aggthndet`.`idaggdet`,
`aggthndet`.`idagg`,
`aggthndet`.`noakun`,
`aggthndet`.`ketdet`,
`aggthndet`.`pagu`,
`aggthndet`.`prosesagg`,
`aggthndet`.`realisasi`,
`aggthndet`.`iu_id_usr`,
`aggthndet`.`iu_wkt`,
`aggthndet`.`iu_stat`FROM `aggthndet`;
```

**Table aggakundet**

```
SELECT `aggakundet`.`id`,
`aggakundet`.`idaggdet`,
`aggakundet`.`ketdetakun`,
`aggakundet`.`volume`,
`aggakundet`.`hrg_satuan`,
`aggakundet`.`iu_id_usr`,
`aggakundet`.`iu_wkt`,
`aggakundet`.`iu_stat`
FROM `aggakundet`;
```

The tables are mutually related to each other **(relationship one-to-many)**

i want insert data into table **aggakundet**, and update column **pagu** on table **aggthndet**, **pagu** column is the sum of the overall **jml_total (alias column)** of columns that have the same **idaggdet**.

**sample data**

[table aggthndet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JiN3.png) 
[table aggakundet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBkPb.png)

Comment: ok, and is there a question?

Comment: what you are tried?

Comment: Pls elaborate your question with **sample data, primary key and foreign key** relations between two tables.

Comment: @viki888: please check updated question...

Comment: Paste your sample query which you have tried. This is simple scenario, which can be achieved using small SP in MySQL. How are you inserting records into table **aggakundet**?

Comment: @viki888: this is my query http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2d3k-z97g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you are having the value of **`idaggdet`** in **$idaggdet**.

Once insertion is done, proceed with **UPDATE** using the values in **$idaggdet**

You can take the below query as reference,

```
UPDATE `aggthndet`
SET `pagu` = `pagu`+1
WHERE `idaggdet` = '$idaggdet';
```

You can append this update statement in **$sql** itself.

Comment: so I don't need to use the command join in the sql statement?

Comment: No. You already have the value for `idaggdet` in **$idaggdet**, then there is no need to join with table`aggakundet`.

Comment: i was update my script like this [Updated](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kv86-udnz)